# CustomEventWrapper passed into DomRepeatModel.fromEvent not returning List Item

Tags: polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I have List of Maps I am using a `<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}" as="row">`

which makes sense, and then I have a Polymer *paper-button* which calls an event.  I define the method as:

```
void edit(CustomEventWrapper cew, Map data){
  var mnodel = new DomRepeatModel.fromEvent(cew);
}
```

but model itself isnt correct, as that returns a DomRepeatModel.

Next I was looking at the method / properties which allow me to determine the map again.

It shows that *item* is depricated, so i shouldnt be using that but instead use `[]`, so i tried: `['item']` which was null.  I checked that `.item` gave me the map.

Answer (score 0):

in the square brackets `[]` you need to pass the key of whatever you set it as in the template.

In this case, say:

```
void edit(CustomEventWrapper cew, Map data){
  var model = new DomRepeatModel.fromEvent(cew)["row"];

  print("Your model is: $model");
}
```